# Using multiple columns to while mapping dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to use multiple columns for creating a new column while using a dictionary to create the new columns values. Simple example below:

df:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3
Dog      Bird    Cat
Blue     Red     Black
Bad      Sad     Glad
```

`my_dict = {'Bird': 'AAA','Blue':'BBB','Glad':'ZZZ'}`

desired df:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3      NewCol
Dog      Bird    Cat       AAA
Blue     Red     Black     BBB
Bad      Sad     Glad      ZZZ
```

I've played around with the map function (df.NewCol = df.Col.map(my_dict))... but it only allows me to use one column to search for the keys in my dictionary. I need the Col1, Col2, AND Col3 columns to search through my dictionary in order to create NewCol.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: What happens if a row has both 'Bird' and 'Blue' for instance? Do you give precedence based on the Column, or based on the values in the dictionary somehow?

Comment: @ALollz.... in my dataset, a situation like you are describing won't occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**: apply `map` with `ffill`. This doesn't assume one valid entry per row.

```
# this will take the last occurrence of valid entry in a row
# change to .bfill(1).iloc[:,0] to get the first
df['NewCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(my_dict)).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

**Option 2**: `map` on `stack` and assign. This approach assumes only one valid entry per row.

```
df['NewCol'] = (df.stack().map(my_dict)
                  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                  .dropna()
               )
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2   Col3 NewCol
0   Dog  Bird    Cat    AAA
1  Blue   Red  Black    BBB
2   Bad   Sad   Glad    ZZZ
```

Comment: I like `df.stack().map(my_dict).groupby(level=0).first()`

Comment: I totally forgot about `applymap`: `df.applymap(my_dict.get).bfill(1).iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: @piRSquared My impression is that `applymap`, like `apply`, is generally not vectorized. I can be wrong though

Comment: I haven't tested it in a long time.  But at some point it improved substantially.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using more Python stuff in a comprehension

This is more obtuse... but I think it's fun.  Likely faster in some contexts but probably not worth the added confusion.

```
df.assign(NewCol=[min(map(my_dict.get, t), key=pd.isna) for t in zip(*map(df.get, df))])

   Col1  Col2   Col3 NewCol
0   Dog  Bird    Cat    AAA
1  Blue   Red  Black    BBB
2   Bad   Sad   Glad    ZZZ
```

Comment: I always like your out of the box thinking :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Another way uses `replace` on dataframe and compare against `df` and `ffill`

```
df['NewCol'] = df.replace(my_dict).where(lambda x: x != df).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]

Out[550]:
   Col1  Col2   Col3 NewCol
0   Dog  Bird    Cat    AAA
1  Blue   Red  Black    BBB
2   Bad   Sad   Glad    ZZZ
```

Or Use `stack`, `droplevel`

```
df['NewCol'] = df.replace(my_dict).where(lambda x: x != df).stack().droplevel(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a row has one key and one key only, another approach would be chaining `map`, `ravel` and `dropna` as below:

```
df['NewCol'] = pd.Series(df.apply(lambda x: x.map(my_dict)).values.ravel()).dropna().values
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2   Col3 NewCol
0   Dog  Bird    Cat    AAA
1  Blue   Red  Black    BBB
2   Bad   Sad   Glad    ZZZ
```